# Post build event error when building project.sln with CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, visual-studio-2017, post-build-event

I've been tasked with converting and building a large framework into a CMake tree and binary. Currently, the framework is built using VS 2017, creating a solution named Framework_static_vc15.sln. As this is a large project, I opted to use a converter to create the CMakeLists.txt files for each part of this project. Here is the link to the converter I used.

https://cmakeconverter.readthedocs.io/en/develop/intro.html

This converter successfully creates all the text files needed, and I can run the command

```
cmake -S . -B build
```

To create a directory that I should be able to run `cmake --build build` on.
However, when I run the above command, the build fails every time with the following error

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(1
38,5): error MSB3073: The command "setlocal [C:\Work\SVN\Software\Framework\build\Source\UeiDaqCore\UeiDaqCore_vc15.vcx
proj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(1
38,5): error MSB3073: cd C:\Work\SVN\Software\Framework\Source\UeiDaqCore [C:\Work\SVN\Software\Framework\build\Source\
UeiDaqCore\UeiDaqCore_vc15.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(1
38,5): error MSB3073: if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd [C:\Work\SVN\Software\Framework\build\Source\UeiDaqCore\UeiDaqC
ore_vc15.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(1
38,5): error MSB3073: C: [C:\Work\SVN\Software\Framework\build\Source\UeiDaqCore\UeiDaqCore_vc15.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(1
38,5): error MSB3073: if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd [C:\Work\SVN\Software\Framework\build\Source\UeiDaqCore\UeiDaqC
ore_vc15.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(1
38,5): error MSB3073: if not exist ..\..\CPP\lib mkdir ..\..\CPP\lib [C:\Work\SVN\Software\Framework\build\Source\UeiDa
qCore\UeiDaqCore_vc15.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(1
38,5): error MSB3073: if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd [C:\Work\SVN\Software\Framework\build\Source\UeiDaqCore\UeiDaqC
ore_vc15.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(1
38,5): error MSB3073: copy C:\Work\SVN\Software\Framework\Source\UeiDaqCore\..\..\Output\Win32\vs15_DebugUeiDaqvc15SD.l
ib ..\..\CPP\lib [C:\Work\SVN\Software\Framework\build\Source\UeiDaqCore\UeiDaqCore_vc15.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(1
38,5): error MSB3073: if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd [C:\Work\SVN\Software\Framework\build\Source\UeiDaqCore\UeiDaqC
ore_vc15.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(1
38,5): error MSB3073: cd.      [C:\Work\SVN\Software\Framework\build\Source\UeiDaqCore\UeiDaqCore_vc15.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(1
38,5): error MSB3073: if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd [C:\Work\SVN\Software\Framework\build\Source\UeiDaqCore\UeiDaqC
ore_vc15.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(1
38,5): error MSB3073: cd.   [C:\Work\SVN\Software\Framework\build\Source\UeiDaqCore\UeiDaqCore_vc15.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(1
38,5): error MSB3073: if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd [C:\Work\SVN\Software\Framework\build\Source\UeiDaqCore\UeiDaqC
ore_vc15.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(1
38,5): error MSB3073: :cmEnd [C:\Work\SVN\Software\Framework\build\Source\UeiDaqCore\UeiDaqCore_vc15.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(1
38,5): error MSB3073: endlocal & call :cmErrorLevel %errorlevel% & goto :cmDone [C:\Work\SVN\Software\Framework\build\S
ource\UeiDaqCore\UeiDaqCore_vc15.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(1
38,5): error MSB3073: :cmErrorLevel [C:\Work\SVN\Software\Framework\build\Source\UeiDaqCore\UeiDaqCore_vc15.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(1
38,5): error MSB3073: exit /b %1 [C:\Work\SVN\Software\Framework\build\Source\UeiDaqCore\UeiDaqCore_vc15.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(1
38,5): error MSB3073: :cmDone [C:\Work\SVN\Software\Framework\build\Source\UeiDaqCore\UeiDaqCore_vc15.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(1
38,5): error MSB3073: if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :VCEnd [C:\Work\SVN\Software\Framework\build\Source\UeiDaqCore\UeiDaqC
ore_vc15.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(1
38,5): error MSB3073: :VCEnd" exited with code 1. [C:\Work\SVN\Software\Framework\build\Source\UeiDaqCore\UeiDaqCore_vc
15.vcxproj]
```

This error is from a post build event inside a sub-project named UeiDaqCore, that arises when CMake tries to execute the following command `UeiDaqCore_vc15.vcxproj -> C:\Work\SVN\Software\Framework\Output\Win32\vs15_Debug\UeiDaqCore_vc15SD.lib`. CMake gives me the error list without all the paths, and here it is.

```
PostBuildEvent:
  setlocal
  cd C:\Work\SVN\Software\Framework\Source\UeiDaqCore
  if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd
  C:
  if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd
  if not exist ..\..\CPP\lib mkdir ..\..\CPP\lib
  if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd
  copy C:\Work\SVN\Software\Framework\Source\UeiDaqCore\..\..\Output\Win32\vs15_DebugUeiDaqvc15SD.lib ..\..\CPP\lib
  if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd
  cd.
  if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd
  cd.
  if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd
  :cmEnd
  endlocal & call :cmErrorLevel %errorlevel% & goto :cmDone
  :cmErrorLevel
  exit /b %1
  :cmDone
  if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :VCEnd
  :VCEnd
  The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I looked through the Visual Studio UeiDaqCore project file for post build events named `setlocal`, and I also looked through the CmakeLists.txt files for `setlocal` post build events, but could find none. 
From the error text, it looks like it's looking for a project named `UeiDaqCore_vc15.vcxproj` and a file named `UeiDaqCore_vc15SD.lib`, but cant find it. I'm not sure why, because both files are located in the folder its looking in.

I am running CMake with the administrator command prompt, as I've seen others who have had this problem, and it was caused by no admin privileges. Below this, I'll post the full CmakeLists.txt for the UeiDaqCore subproject.

```
project(UeiDaqCore_vc15 CXX)

################################################################################
# Source groups
################################################################################
set(no_group_source_files
    ReadMe.txt
)
source_group("" FILES ${no_group_source_files})

set(Headers
    ../../CPP/include/UeiChannel.h
    ../../CPP/include/UeiConstants.h
    ../../CPP/include/UeiCustomScale.h
    ../../CPP/include/UeiDaq.h
    ../../CPP/include/UeiDaqAnsiC.h
    ../../CPP/include/UeiDaqError.h
    ../../CPP/include/UeiDataStream.h
    ../../CPP/include/UeiDevice.h
    ../../CPP/include/UeiDeviceEnumerator.h
    ../../CPP/include/UeiDriverEnumerator.h
    ../../CPP/include/UeiEvent.h
    ../../CPP/include/UeiException.h
    ../../CPP/include/UeiFrameUtils.h
    ../../CPP/include/UeiMessaging.h
    ../../CPP/include/UeiObject.h
    ../../CPP/include/UeiReader.h
    ../../CPP/include/UeiResourceParser.h
    ../../CPP/include/UeiSession.h
    ../../CPP/include/UeiSessionGroup.h
    ../../CPP/include/UeiStructs.h
    ../../CPP/include/Ueisystem.h
    ../../CPP/include/UeiTiming.h
    ../../CPP/include/UeiTrigger.h
    ../../CPP/include/UeiWriter.h
    pugxml.h
    resource.h
    ResourceParser.h
    SensorConversion.h
    SignalParser.h
    StdAfx.h
    UeiAnsiCSession.h
    UeiChannelimpl.h
    UeiCJCConverter.h
    UeiDaqCore.h
    UeiDaqCoreVer.h
    UeiDaqDriver.h
    UeiDaqDriverSession.h
    UeiDaqLV.h
    UeiDataStreamImpl.h
    UeiDeviceEnumeratorImpl.h
    UeiDeviceImpl.h
    UeiDriverEvent.h
    UeiMessagingImpl.h
    UeiObjectImpl.h
    UeiReaderImpl.h
    UeiRTDConverter.h
    UeiSessionImpl.h
    UeiSessionSettings.h
    UeiTimingImpl.h
    UeiTriggerImpl.h
    UeiWriterImpl.h
    UeiXmlParser.h
)
source_group("Headers" FILES ${Headers})

set(Sources
    ResourceParser.cpp
    SensorConversion.cpp
    StdAfx.cpp
    UeiChannel.cpp
    UeiChannelImpl.cpp
    UeiCJCConverter.cpp
    UeiCustomScale.cpp
    UeiDaqAnsiC.cpp
    UeiDaqCore.cpp
    UeiDaqLV.cpp
    UeiDataStream.cpp
    UeiDataStreamImpl.cpp
    UeiDevice.cpp
    UeiDeviceEnumerator.cpp
    UeiDeviceEnumeratorImpl.cpp
    UeiDeviceImpl.cpp
    UeiDriverEnumerator.cpp
    UeiException.cpp
    UeiFrameUtils.cpp
    UeiMessaging.cpp
    UeiMessagingImpl.cpp
    UeiObject.cpp
    UeiObjectImpl.cpp
    UeiReader.cpp
    UeiReaderImpl.cpp
    UeiResourceParser.cpp
    UeiRTDConverter.cpp
    UeiSession.cpp
    UeiSessionGroup.cpp
    UeiSessionImpl.cpp
    UeiSessionSettings.cpp
    UeiSystem.cpp
    UeiTiming.cpp
    UeiTimingImpl.cpp
    UeiTrigger.cpp
    UeiTriggerImpl.cpp
    UeiWriter.cpp
    UeiWriterImpl.cpp
    UeiXmlParser.cpp
)
source_group("Sources" FILES ${Sources})

set(ALL_FILES
    ${no_group_source_files}
    ${Headers}
    ${Sources}
)

################################################################################
# Target
################################################################################
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} STATIC ${ALL_FILES})

add_precompiled_header(${PROJECT_NAME} "StdAfx.h" "StdAfx.cpp")

use_props(${PROJECT_NAME} "${CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES}" "${DEFAULT_CXX_PROPS}")
set(ROOT_NAMESPACE UeiDaqCore)

################################################################################
# Target name
################################################################################
set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES
    TARGET_NAME_DEBUG   "${PROJECT_NAME}SD"
    TARGET_NAME_RELEASE "${PROJECT_NAME}S"
)
################################################################################
# Output directory
################################################################################
set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES
    OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_DEBUG   "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../Output/${CMAKE_VS_PLATFORM_NAME}/vs15_$<CONFIG>"
    OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../Output/${CMAKE_VS_PLATFORM_NAME}/vs15_$<CONFIG>"
)
################################################################################
# Include directories
################################################################################
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../CPP/include;"
    "$ENV{UEICOMMON}/includes"
)

################################################################################
# Compile definitions
################################################################################
target_compile_definitions(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE
    "$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:"
        "_DEBUG;"
        "UEIDAQ_DEBUG"
    ">"
    "$<$<CONFIG:Release>:"
        "NDEBUG"
    ">"
    "WIN32;"
    "_WINDOWS;"
    "UEIDAQSTATIC;"
    "__MSWINDOWS__;"
    "_MBCS"
)
set_source_files_properties(ResourceParser.cpp PROPERTIES
    COMPILE_DEFINITIONS_DEBUG "_DEBUG"
    COMPILE_DEFINITIONS_RELEASE "NDEBUG"
    COMPILE_DEFINITIONS "WIN32;_WINDOWS;_MBCS;_USRDLL;UEIDAQCORE_EXPORTS"
)
set_source_files_properties(StdAfx.cpp PROPERTIES
    COMPILE_DEFINITIONS_DEBUG "_DEBUG"
    COMPILE_DEFINITIONS_RELEASE "NDEBUG"
    COMPILE_DEFINITIONS "WIN32;_WINDOWS;_MBCS;UEIDAQSTATIC"
)
set_source_files_properties(UeiChannel.cpp PROPERTIES
    COMPILE_DEFINITIONS_DEBUG "_DEBUG"
    COMPILE_DEFINITIONS_RELEASE "NDEBUG"
    COMPILE_DEFINITIONS "WIN32;_WINDOWS;_MBCS;_USRDLL;UEIDAQCORE_EXPORTS"
)
set_source_files_properties(UeiChannelImpl.cpp PROPERTIES
    COMPILE_DEFINITIONS_DEBUG "_DEBUG"
    COMPILE_DEFINITIONS_RELEASE "NDEBUG"
    COMPILE_DEFINITIONS "WIN32;_WINDOWS;_MBCS;_USRDLL;UEIDAQCORE_EXPORTS"
)
set_source_files_properties(UeiDaqCore.cpp PROPERTIES
    COMPILE_DEFINITIONS_DEBUG "_DEBUG"
    COMPILE_DEFINITIONS_RELEASE "NDEBUG"
    COMPILE_DEFINITIONS "WIN32;_WINDOWS;_MBCS;_USRDLL;UEIDAQCORE_EXPORTS"
)
set_source_files_properties(UeiDataStream.cpp PROPERTIES
    COMPILE_DEFINITIONS_DEBUG "_DEBUG"
    COMPILE_DEFINITIONS_RELEASE "NDEBUG"
    COMPILE_DEFINITIONS "WIN32;_WINDOWS;_MBCS;_USRDLL;UEIDAQCORE_EXPORTS"
)
set_source_files_properties(UeiDataStreamImpl.cpp PROPERTIES
    COMPILE_DEFINITIONS_DEBUG "_DEBUG"
    COMPILE_DEFINITIONS_RELEASE "NDEBUG"
    COMPILE_DEFINITIONS "WIN32;_WINDOWS;_MBCS;_USRDLL;UEIDAQCORE_EXPORTS"
)
set_source_files_properties(UeiDevice.cpp PROPERTIES
    COMPILE_DEFINITIONS_DEBUG "_DEBUG"
    COMPILE_DEFINITIONS_RELEASE "NDEBUG"
    COMPILE_DEFINITIONS "WIN32;_WINDOWS;_MBCS;_USRDLL;UEIDAQCORE_EXPORTS"
)
set_source_files_properties(UeiDeviceEnumerator.cpp PROPERTIES
    COMPILE_DEFINITIONS_DEBUG "_DEBUG"
    COMPILE_DEFINITIONS_RELEASE "NDEBUG"
    COMPILE_DEFINITIONS "WIN32;_WINDOWS;_MBCS;_USRDLL;UEIDAQCORE_EXPORTS"
)
set_source_files_properties(UeiDeviceEnumeratorImpl.cpp PROPERTIES
    COMPILE_DEFINITIONS_DEBUG "_DEBUG"
    COMPILE_DEFINITIONS_RELEASE "NDEBUG"
    COMPILE_DEFINITIONS "WIN32;_WINDOWS;_MBCS;_USRDLL;UEIDAQCORE_EXPORTS"
)
set_source_files_properties(UeiDeviceImpl.cpp PROPERTIES
    COMPILE_DEFINITIONS_DEBUG "_DEBUG"
    COMPILE_DEFINITIONS_RELEASE "NDEBUG"
    COMPILE_DEFINITIONS "WIN32;_WINDOWS;_MBCS;_USRDLL;UEIDAQCORE_EXPORTS"
)
set_source_files_properties(UeiException.cpp PROPERTIES
    COMPILE_DEFINITIONS_DEBUG "_DEBUG"
    COMPILE_DEFINITIONS_RELEASE "NDEBUG"
    COMPILE_DEFINITIONS "WIN32;_WINDOWS;_MBCS;_USRDLL;UEIDAQCORE_EXPORTS"
)
set_source_files_properties(UeiObject.cpp PROPERTIES
    COMPILE_DEFINITIONS_DEBUG "_DEBUG"
    COMPILE_DEFINITIONS_RELEASE "NDEBUG"
    COMPILE_DEFINITIONS "WIN32;_WINDOWS;_MBCS;_USRDLL;UEIDAQCORE_EXPORTS"
)
set_source_files_properties(UeiObjectImpl.cpp PROPERTIES
    COMPILE_DEFINITIONS_DEBUG "_DEBUG"
    COMPILE_DEFINITIONS_RELEASE "NDEBUG"
    COMPILE_DEFINITIONS "WIN32;_WINDOWS;_MBCS;_USRDLL;UEIDAQCORE_EXPORTS"
)
set_source_files_properties(UeiSession.cpp PROPERTIES
    COMPILE_DEFINITIONS_DEBUG "_DEBUG"
    COMPILE_DEFINITIONS_RELEASE "NDEBUG"
    COMPILE_DEFINITIONS "WIN32;_WINDOWS;_MBCS;_USRDLL;UEIDAQCORE_EXPORTS"
)
set_source_files_properties(UeiSessionGroup.cpp PROPERTIES
    COMPILE_DEFINITIONS_DEBUG "_DEBUG"
    COMPILE_DEFINITIONS_RELEASE "NDEBUG"
    COMPILE_DEFINITIONS "WIN32;_WINDOWS;_MBCS;_USRDLL;UEIDAQCORE_EXPORTS"
)
set_source_files_properties(UeiSessionImpl.cpp PROPERTIES
    COMPILE_DEFINITIONS_DEBUG "_DEBUG"
    COMPILE_DEFINITIONS_RELEASE "NDEBUG"
    COMPILE_DEFINITIONS "WIN32;_WINDOWS;_MBCS;_USRDLL;UEIDAQCORE_EXPORTS"
)
set_source_files_properties(UeiTiming.cpp PROPERTIES
    COMPILE_DEFINITIONS_DEBUG "_DEBUG"
    COMPILE_DEFINITIONS_RELEASE "NDEBUG"
    COMPILE_DEFINITIONS "WIN32;_WINDOWS;_MBCS;_USRDLL;UEIDAQCORE_EXPORTS"
)
set_source_files_properties(UeiTimingImpl.cpp PROPERTIES
    COMPILE_DEFINITIONS_DEBUG "_DEBUG"
    COMPILE_DEFINITIONS_RELEASE "NDEBUG"
    COMPILE_DEFINITIONS "WIN32;_WINDOWS;_MBCS;_USRDLL;UEIDAQCORE_EXPORTS"
)
set_source_files_properties(UeiTrigger.cpp PROPERTIES
    COMPILE_DEFINITIONS_DEBUG "_DEBUG"
    COMPILE_DEFINITIONS_RELEASE "NDEBUG"
    COMPILE_DEFINITIONS "WIN32;_WINDOWS;_MBCS;_USRDLL;UEIDAQCORE_EXPORTS"
)
set_source_files_properties(UeiTriggerImpl.cpp PROPERTIES
    COMPILE_DEFINITIONS_DEBUG "_DEBUG"
    COMPILE_DEFINITIONS_RELEASE "NDEBUG"
    COMPILE_DEFINITIONS "WIN32;_WINDOWS;_MBCS;_USRDLL;UEIDAQCORE_EXPORTS"
)

################################################################################
# Compile and link options
################################################################################
if(MSVC)
    target_compile_options(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE
        $<$<CONFIG:Debug>:
            /Od;
            /RTC1;
            /MTd
        >
        $<$<CONFIG:Release>:
            /O2;
            /Ob1;
            /GF;
            /MT;
            /Gy
        >
        /W3;
        /nologo;
        /Zi;
        /GR;
        ${DEFAULT_CXX_EXCEPTION_HANDLING}
    )
    string(CONCAT FILE_CL_OPTIONS
        "$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:"
            "/Od;/RTC1"
        ">"
        "$<$<CONFIG:Release>:"
            "/O2"
        ">"
    )
    source_file_compile_options(ResourceParser.cpp ${FILE_CL_OPTIONS})
    string(CONCAT FILE_CL_OPTIONS
        "$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:"
            "/Od;/RTC1"
        ">"
        "$<$<CONFIG:Release>:"
            "/O2"
        ">"
    )
    source_file_compile_options(StdAfx.cpp ${FILE_CL_OPTIONS})
    string(CONCAT FILE_CL_OPTIONS
        "$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:"
            "/Od;/RTC1"
        ">"
        "$<$<CONFIG:Release>:"
            "/O2"
        ">"
    )
    source_file_compile_options(UeiChannel.cpp ${FILE_CL_OPTIONS})
    string(CONCAT FILE_CL_OPTIONS
        "$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:"
            "/Od;/RTC1"
        ">"
        "$<$<CONFIG:Release>:"
            "/O2"
        ">"
    )
    source_file_compile_options(UeiChannelImpl.cpp ${FILE_CL_OPTIONS})
    string(CONCAT FILE_CL_OPTIONS
        "$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:"
            "/Od;/RTC1"
        ">"
        "$<$<CONFIG:Release>:"
            "/O2"
        ">"
    )
    source_file_compile_options(UeiDaqCore.cpp ${FILE_CL_OPTIONS})
    string(CONCAT FILE_CL_OPTIONS
        "$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:"
            "/Od;/RTC1"
        ">"
        "$<$<CONFIG:Release>:"
            "/O2"
        ">"
    )
    source_file_compile_options(UeiDataStream.cpp ${FILE_CL_OPTIONS})
    string(CONCAT FILE_CL_OPTIONS
        "$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:"
            "/Od;/RTC1"
        ">"
        "$<$<CONFIG:Release>:"
            "/O2"
        ">"
    )
    source_file_compile_options(UeiDataStreamImpl.cpp ${FILE_CL_OPTIONS})
    string(CONCAT FILE_CL_OPTIONS
        "$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:"
            "/Od;/RTC1"
        ">"
        "$<$<CONFIG:Release>:"
            "/O2"
        ">"
    )
    source_file_compile_options(UeiDevice.cpp ${FILE_CL_OPTIONS})
    string(CONCAT FILE_CL_OPTIONS
        "$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:"
            "/Od;/RTC1"
        ">"
        "$<$<CONFIG:Release>:"
            "/O2"
        ">"
    )
    source_file_compile_options(UeiDeviceEnumerator.cpp ${FILE_CL_OPTIONS})
    string(CONCAT FILE_CL_OPTIONS
        "$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:"
            "/Od;/RTC1"
        ">"
        "$<$<CONFIG:Release>:"
            "/O2"
        ">"
    )
    source_file_compile_options(UeiDeviceEnumeratorImpl.cpp ${FILE_CL_OPTIONS})
    string(CONCAT FILE_CL_OPTIONS
        "$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:"
            "/Od;/RTC1"
        ">"
        "$<$<CONFIG:Release>:"
            "/O2"
        ">"
    )
    source_file_compile_options(UeiDeviceImpl.cpp ${FILE_CL_OPTIONS})
    string(CONCAT FILE_CL_OPTIONS
        "$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:"
            "/Od;/RTC1"
        ">"
        "$<$<CONFIG:Release>:"
            "/O2"
        ">"
    )
    source_file_compile_options(UeiException.cpp ${FILE_CL_OPTIONS})
    string(CONCAT FILE_CL_OPTIONS
        "$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:"
            "/Od;/RTC1"
        ">"
        "$<$<CONFIG:Release>:"
            "/O2"
        ">"
    )
    source_file_compile_options(UeiObject.cpp ${FILE_CL_OPTIONS})
    string(CONCAT FILE_CL_OPTIONS
        "$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:"
            "/Od;/RTC1"
        ">"
        "$<$<CONFIG:Release>:"
            "/O2"
        ">"
    )
    source_file_compile_options(UeiObjectImpl.cpp ${FILE_CL_OPTIONS})
    string(CONCAT FILE_CL_OPTIONS
        "$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:"
            "/Od;/RTC1"
        ">"
        "$<$<CONFIG:Release>:"
            "/O2"
        ">"
    )
    source_file_compile_options(UeiSession.cpp ${FILE_CL_OPTIONS})
    string(CONCAT FILE_CL_OPTIONS
        "$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:"
            "/Od;/RTC1"
        ">"
        "$<$<CONFIG:Release>:"
            "/O2"
        ">"
    )
    source_file_compile_options(UeiSessionGroup.cpp ${FILE_CL_OPTIONS})
    string(CONCAT FILE_CL_OPTIONS
        "$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:"
            "/Od;/RTC1"
        ">"
        "$<$<CONFIG:Release>:"
            "/O2"
        ">"
    )
    source_file_compile_options(UeiSessionImpl.cpp ${FILE_CL_OPTIONS})
    string(CONCAT FILE_CL_OPTIONS
        "$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:"
            "/Od;/RTC1"
        ">"
        "$<$<CONFIG:Release>:"
            "/O2"
        ">"
    )
    source_file_compile_options(UeiTiming.cpp ${FILE_CL_OPTIONS})
    string(CONCAT FILE_CL_OPTIONS
        "$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:"
            "/Od;/RTC1"
        ">"
        "$<$<CONFIG:Release>:"
            "/O2"
        ">"
    )
    source_file_compile_options(UeiTimingImpl.cpp ${FILE_CL_OPTIONS})
    string(CONCAT FILE_CL_OPTIONS
        "$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:"
            "/Od;/RTC1"
        ">"
        "$<$<CONFIG:Release>:"
            "/O2"
        ">"
    )
    source_file_compile_options(UeiTrigger.cpp ${FILE_CL_OPTIONS})
    string(CONCAT FILE_CL_OPTIONS
        "$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:"
            "/Od;/RTC1"
        ">"
        "$<$<CONFIG:Release>:"
            "/O2"
        ">"
    )
    source_file_compile_options(UeiTriggerImpl.cpp ${FILE_CL_OPTIONS})
endif()

################################################################################
# Post build events
################################################################################
add_custom_command_if(
    TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME}
    POST_BUILD
    COMMANDS
    COMMAND   $<CONFIG:Debug> if not exist ..\\..\\CPP\\lib mkdir ..\\..\\CPP\\lib
    COMMAND   $<CONFIG:Debug> copy $<SHELL_PATH:${OUTPUT_DIRECTORY}>UeiDaqvc15SD.lib ..\\..\\CPP\\lib
    COMMAND $<CONFIG:Release> if not exist ..\\..\\CPP\\lib mkdir ..\\..\\CPP\\lib
    COMMAND $<CONFIG:Release> copy $<SHELL_PATH:${OUTPUT_DIRECTORY}>UeiDaqvc15S.lib ..\\..\\CPP\\lib
)

################################################################################
# Dependencies
################################################################################
add_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME}
    UeiPDNADriver_vc15
    UeiSimuDriver_vc15
)

# Link with other targets.
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC
    UeiPDNADriver_vc15
    UeiSimuDriver_vc15
)
```

I'm quite new to CMake, and any help towards a possible solution would be appreciated.

EDIT: Here are the post build events for UeiDaqCore copied directly from the Visual Studio window.

```
copy "$(SolutionDir)\Output\$(Platform)\vs15_$(Configuration)\UeiDaqvc15D.dll" "$(SystemRoot)\System32"
if not exist ..\..\CPP\lib mkdir ..\..\CPP\lib
copy "$(SolutionDir)\Output\$(Platform)\vs15_$(Configuration)\UeiDaqvc15D.lib" ..\..\CPP\lib
```

Comment: @squareskittles yes both files exist. UeiDaqCore_vc15SD.lib is sitting right in the directory its looking in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the `POST_BUILD` custom command is malformed. Specifically, the `copy` command is not putting a path separator between the defined `OUTPUT_DIRECTORY`:

```
C:\Work\SVN\Software\Framework\Source\UeiDaqCore\..\..\Output\Win32\vs15_Debug
```

from the file name:

```
UeiDaqvc15SD.lib
```

So they get (mistakenly) concatenated:

```
C:\Work\SVN\Software\Framework\Source\UeiDaqCore\..\..\Output\Win32\vs15_DebugUeiDaqvc15SD.lib
```

Try adding path separators `\\` in the custom command after `$<SHELL_PATH:${OUTPUT_DIRECTORY}>`:

```
add_custom_command_if(
    TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME}
    POST_BUILD
    COMMANDS
    COMMAND   $<CONFIG:Debug> if not exist ..\\..\\CPP\\lib mkdir ..\\..\\CPP\\lib
    COMMAND   $<CONFIG:Debug> copy $<SHELL_PATH:${OUTPUT_DIRECTORY}>\\UeiDaqvc15SD.lib ..\\..\\CPP\\lib
    COMMAND $<CONFIG:Release> if not exist ..\\..\\CPP\\lib mkdir ..\\..\\CPP\\lib
    COMMAND $<CONFIG:Release> copy $<SHELL_PATH:${OUTPUT_DIRECTORY}>\\UeiDaqvc15S.lib ..\\..\\CPP\\lib
)
```

Comment: It looks like the same exact error is being thrown, doesnt look like anything has changed after I added the ```\\``` after the ```$<SHELL_PATH:${OUTPUT_DIRECTORY}>```

Comment: @Bendrix It may help to put quotes around the entire expressions `"$<SHELL_PATH:${OUTPUT_DIRECTORY}>\\UeiDaqvc15SD.lib"`, but it is working without quotes on my machine. Consider clearing the CMake cache and running CMake from scratch if you haven't done so already.

Comment: I added quotes, still threw error. Ill clear the cache and try completely rebuilding the project.

Comment: The edit to your question post shows that the library name is *no longer* concatenated with the path: `$(SolutionDir)\Output\$(Platform)\vs15_$(Configuration)\UeiDaqvc15D.lib`. However, now, the library name seems to be missed an `S` that was there before. Have you renamed the libraries since your original posting?

Comment: No. I havent renamed anything at all. The build events came when I pulled the framework from the version control, and the post build events within the .txt file were auto generated. I dont know why theyre so different, im thinking an issue with the .txt generator. Would it be best for me to just hardcode the file paths for the existing files instead of leaving the generator to come up with the paths? I cleared the cache and rebuilt the .txt files and the same error occurred.

Comment: I checked the post build event for the UeiDaqCore and then compared it to the name of the .lib file the project was building and for some reason it was being renamed during building. I changed the name in the post build event and it worked. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Bendrix I think the paths are OK, but it's still odd to me that the library built by the CMake code you provided (`UeiDaqCore_vc15SD.lib`) is different from the library name that the `POST_BUILD` event tries to copy (`UeiDaqvc15SD.lib`). But, I'm not familiar with the codebase so I'm not sure what this second `UeiDaqvc15SD.lib` library is for, or where it is built. It would seem the custom command should just copy the library it built with something like: `$<SHELL_PATH:${OUTPUT_DIRECTORY}>\\${PROJECT_NAME}SD.lib`